# Activator Dependencies Error

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt, typesafe-activator

***Version***

```
        sbt.version=0.13.8

        name := """sample_app"""

        version := "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

        scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
```

***Resolver***

```
        resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
```

***All Plugins***

```
        // The Play plugin
        addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.3")

        // web plugins

        addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")

        addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.6")

        addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")

        addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")

        addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")

        addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")

        addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

***Dependencies Error***

I create new project using ***Activator***, In command prompt I execute the command ***activator dependencies*** The result is

```
     E:\sample_app>activator dependencies
[info] Loading project definition from E:\sample_app\project
[info] Set current project to sample_app (in build file:/E:/sample_app/)
[error] Not a valid command: dependencies
[error] Not a valid project ID: dependencies
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: dependencies (similar: all-dependencies, rpm-dependencies, allDependencies)
[error] dependencies
[error]             ^
```

***Versions used:***

```
    Java version is 1.8.0_51,
    Activator is 1.3.6,
    OS is windows 8,
    64 - bit OS.
```

Please give me a solution...

Comment: spell miss: `dependecies` -> `dependencies`

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the dependencies, as activator hinted you need a different setting.

Do

```
activator "show allDependencies"
```

Comment: Yeah I try that one the result is:

E:\sample_app>activator show allDependencies
[info] Loading project definition from E:\sample_app\project
[info] Set current project to sample_app (in build file:/E:/sample_app/)
**[error] Not a valid command: show (similar: shell)
[error] Expected whitespace character
[error] Not a valid project ID: show
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: show (similar: showTiming, showSuccess, show-timing)
[error] show
[error]     ^** @Ajay Padala

Comment: You didn't put quotes (") around show allDependencies

Comment: Yeah I didn't use (") sir...

 **E:\sample_app>activator show allDependencies**

Use This command only